# Prove inequality so I can use Banach fixed point thrm

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, fixed-point-theorems

I have the function $\varphi(x)=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-x^2}}$.
I want to prove that $d(\varphi(x),\varphi(y)\leq k\cdot d(x,y)$ for some $k,\ \forall x,y$.
I thoight it would be simple, just by saying that
$\left|\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-x^2}}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-y^2}}\right|\leq k\cdot |x-y|$ and for x>y I started to compare only $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-x^2}}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-y^2}}=x-y$. But I tried everything, rationalizing, multiplying by the compose, squaring, and I don't come any further. I would be really glad if someone could tell me if there is a trick to it or something.
This is as far as I go...
$\frac{\sqrt{4-y^2}-\sqrt{4-x^2}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-x^2}}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-y^2}}}=x-y
$
$\frac{x^2-y^2}{(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-x^2}}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-y^2}})(\sqrt{4-y^2}+\sqrt{4-x^2})}=x-y \Leftrightarrow \frac{x+1}{(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-x^2}}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-y^2}})(\sqrt{4-y^2}+\sqrt{4-x^2})}=1
$

Comment: Post your attempt for rationalizing (I'm assuming that means difference of squares top and bottom), that should have gotten you somewhere useful for this problem. Also note that $x,y \in [-2.2]$, that will aid your inequalities for this problem.

Comment: @M-S-R The numerator in your last fraction should be $x+y$, right?

Answer (score 1):

[edited]

The domain of $\varphi$ is $[-2,2]$ and its only fixed point is $z=0$. If I understood, your  question concerns the convergence of $x_{n+1} = \varphi(x_n), \quad x_0 \in [-2,2]$, to the fixed point $z=0$.

You can start by noting that $\varphi([-2,2]) = [0,\sqrt{2}]$ and so, in terms of convergence, we can suppose right form the start that this is all about the interval $I=[0, \sqrt{2}]$.

The sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded (all terms belong to $I$) and decreasing (assuming, without loss of generality that $x_0 \in I$) and so it is convergent. There is no need for the fixed point theorem.

if you really want to use the fixed point theorem, you can still use this idea that the original domain can be restricted and proof the boundness of $\varphi'$ in $I$. This way you can conclude that $\varphi$ is Lipschitz on $I$, with $k = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}<1$.

Comment: No, I don't really have a specification for $\omega$. The reason that makes me think it should be possible is that I have a sequence defined as $s_{i+1}=\varphi(s_i)$ and the hint is to find the limit $s_i, i\rightarrow\infty$ using the fixed point theorem. And what I'm trying to prove is the requisite for the theorem

Comment: @M-S-R When you apply the fixed point theorem you need to specify  $\Omega$...